# How to create a datetime from parts in Oracle/PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

I have a date (4/30/2012), an hour (4) and a minute (45). I need to convert that to an Oracle datetime value for comparison in a PLSQL/Oracle SELECT statement. Ideally, there would be a function like this (C# since I know it a little better):

```
var date = "4/30/2012";
var hour = "4";
var minute = "45";
DateTime myDateTime = convertDateTime(date, hour, minute);
```

I have a table with three columns to make up the date and time of an event. I have another table that has items that may or may not match based on their start and end dates. In pseudo SQL, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT 
    G.Name, 
    (SELECT MAX(Cost) 
        FROM CrappyTable AS C 
        WHERE G.StartTime < convertDateTime(C.Date, C.Hour, C.Minute) 
        AND G.EndTime > convertDateTime(C.Date, C.Hour, C.Minute)) as Cost
FROM GoodTable as G
WHERE G.Price < 100.00;
```

> OR "Select name and max cost (from reported cost during a time range)
>   where the price is less than $100."

Is there an existing function that might do something like the above `convertDateTime` function?

Comment: Yeah, I to mean PL/SQL. I don't use Oracle much, so I get my T's and PL's mixed up. I fixed that it my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Concatenate your date and time fields and pass them to TO_DATE (assumes 24 hour clock time):

```
TO_DATE(date||' '||hour||':'||minute,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
```

This will convert your date/time values to an Oracle DATE type.

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
TO_DATE(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') + hour/24 + minute/1440
```