# VBA to SQL Date Comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, vba

I have a SQL query that is pulling data into excel. My VBA code reads in numbers from user inputs and writes the SQL code with these parameters in it.
 I can make the comparisons that I need like part number doing it this way, but I cannot get date comparisons to work.
 In the database I am pulling from is a date column and I have user inputs of day, month, and year.

Basically I need this to work:

```
WEEKENDING_DT >= DATE(2017,01,01)
```

But there is no date function in SQL. 
From my research I also found these ways to do it and none of them work.

```
WEEKENDING_DT >= (CAST(2017 AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)) 

WEEKENDING_DT >= CAST(CAST(2017 AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: [Create datetime from parts on Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11404064/1188513)

Comment: SQL Server?

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)